# LocalTime.parse behaves different on JDK 12

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-12

I have the following code that works perfectly on Oracle JDK 10

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final var localTime = LocalTime.parse("8:00AM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma"));
    System.out.println("Local time is " + localTime);
}
```

It outputs the following...

```
Local time is 08:00
```

When I run the same code on OpenJDK 12 I get this...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '8:00AM' could not be parsed at index 4
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1951)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:463)
    at com.virtualenergyservices.portal.backend.bootstrap.FacilitiesImporter.main(FacilitiesImporter.java:909)
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Different locale?

Comment: I'm getting the same error on JDK 10.0.1

Comment: I tried explicitly setting Locale Canada.

Comment: `AM` doesn't work for me, but `am` does - it seems to be locale specific

Comment: Is it a canadian locale which supports "AM" (I wonder if there is a french canadian locale which doesn't support "AM")

Comment: When setting a locale works, then this question is probably a dupe of: [Unable to parse DateTime-string with AM/PM marker](//stackoverflow.com/q/3618676)

Answer (score 3):

`JDK 11` is updated to use the [CLDR v33](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-33) (refer release notes:  [Updated Locale Data to Unicode CLDR v33](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html)). `CLDR` has many changes as compared to the `JRE` locale data which was the default in `JDK8` and earlier.This leads to exceptions thrown while parsing some locale-dependent fields which were working well with prior JDK versions.

The code in your test case is not working because, for the `en_CA` locale, with `CLDR v33`, the [dayperiod](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/33/by_type/date_&_time.fields.html#6b2fa3ccf14e33a8) looks like `a.m./p.m.`. So, there are two options here :

1. Update the code to use the format specified by `CLDR` as below :

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "CA"));
       final var localTime = LocalTime.parse("8:00a.m.", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma"));
       System.out.println("Local time is " + localTime);
   }
   ```
2. Use the compatibility switch `-Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT` , which supports the locale data bundled with `JRE` , which used to be the default in `JDK8` and earlier versions. `"8:00AM"` will parse correctly with `JDK12` when run with the option mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Locale.Canada does not work.

Locale.US and Locale.ROOT do work.